# How does my laptop work as a web server which will take the data to database 24/7

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I recently made a website but I had a doubt about how to make my laptop work as a server and after deploying if I shut down my laptop will the website work the same manner and give data to database in mongodb cloud atlas or will it show website not reached if it does please solve my doubt and give me a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not running the node.js server then your website will not be accessible.

Why not deploy to the cloud like Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

if your site is deployed on your machine it will no longer be accessible if you are disconnected from the internet network in any way.